# Position overlay div at % from top edge of browser not page top

Tags: jquery

is there a way to position a floated overlay div say "20%" from the top edge of the users browser window - e.g. so not 20% from the top of the `<body>` tag - e.g. so that if user scrolls the page and clicks a link way down the page - the floated overlay div is nicely in view floated "20%" from the top edge of the browser?

Comment: This is somewhat misleadingly put at the moment. It's not possible to get access to the position of the browser window including menus and menu bars and such. However, what you really want is to position something relative to the browser's *content* "window", correct? I.e. the window within which the page is being scrolled?

Comment: If it's the latter, the `position: fixed` CSS property is the solution

Comment: OK thanks - yeh think maybe position: fixed is the solution

Comment: But - changing from position: relative to position: fixed messing up all the positioning relative to other elements...

Comment: Well, you can only have one or the other: your positioning can either be relative to the content area, or some other element, at a given time. No way around it. Are you sure that really is a problem, though? Remember, only one element needs to have `position: fixed`.

Comment: thanks - works with child pos:fixed yes